# where does MySQL 5.6 on Windows 8 get it's configuration?

Tags: windows-8, mysql

Everything I've googled says that the configuration file for MySQL on windows (my.ini) should be found in C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6.  If I look there, there is no "my.ini", but there is a (very minimal) my-default.ini.

Is that being used?

Since that file is so small, where should I be looking for default values for the hundreds of other configuration settings that MySQL provides? (I'm particularly looking for the error log location.)

Comment: I do believe you have to create the file yourself.  Have you tried that?

Comment: I have not, because the server is actually starting and processing requests.  So I guess it's possible that there's a default for every MySQL setting...but I can't find any confirmation of that, or a listing of what the defaults might be.

Comment: `cd \ `, `dir /s my.ini`, leave for a couple of minutes and you will have the answer. (from a command prompt of course).

Comment: Check C:\Windows\System32\

Comment: @ChrisCurvey - I guarantee you there is a default for every setting variable otherwise the server wouldn't work if you didn't configure it.

Comment: @JulianKnight you are the winner.  If you post your solution as an answer, I will be happy to mark it as such

Comment: Just in case @JulianKnight does not get back to us, the full answer is C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini

Comment: Ah but of course I'll get back to you! Although the actual folder is correct on your PC, it may not be on others of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cd \`, `dir /s my.ini`, leave for a couple of minutes and you will have the answer. (from a command prompt of course).

Answer (score 0):

You already found the folder that `my.ini` should reside

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6
```

That folder contains sample `my.ini` files, but none are named `my.ini`.

You have to create the `my.ini` in that folder. You could use one of the samples as a guide.

Perhaps you could do this as an example:

```
cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6
copy my-small.ini my.ini
```

Then, restart mysql and work from there.

I mentioned this in the DBA StackExchange

- `Sep 14, 2011` : [Why a copy of my.ini of other MySQL installation not working on my PC](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4421/why-a-copy-of-my-ini-of-other-mysql-installation-not-working-on-my-pc/5749#5749)
- `Feb 06, 2012` : [MySQL Database and Table Loss](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12247/mysql-database-and-table-loss/12366#12366)
- `Oct 15, 2012` : [How can I enable my-huge file on windows server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/26931/how-can-i-enable-my-huge-file-on-windows-server/26977#26977)

## Give it a Try !!!

CAVEAT

Since you are looking for error log and the `my.ini` does not exist at the moment, the error log is probably not enabled. If it is, it would be in `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data` wuth the name of the Windows machine in the name and ending in `.log`.

Answer (score 0):

Do not waste time searching for files on your entire hard drive, the `my.ini` configuration file is now placed here

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini
```

after msi-install ;)